# sql server 2012 express do not understand Russian letters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have DB which is working with Russian text however when i run queries it shows me this. Database will used by Russians and it has to show Russian text properly!

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it? In the future it will located in Russia and work with Russian version SQL Server but right now I am working on English version SQL 2012 Express.

Here is the table and insert statement:

```
Create table Employee
(
 EmpID int not null IDENTITY (10, 1), 
 StrName nvarchar (25) not null, 
 Phone1 nvarchar (25) not null,
 Phone2 nvarchar (25)
 Primary Key (EmpID),
);
insert into  Employee  (LastName , FirstName,Phone1,Phone2)
  values ('Иванов','111 111 11111','111 111 1111');
```

Comment: Is your column `varchar` or `nvarchar`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you sure the data has been stored in the database correctly? How do you know?

Make sure that the column has a proper collation, that it is defined as `nvarchar` and that inserts of string literals are prefixed with `N`. For example, these are not the same:

```
INSERT dbo.table(column) SELECT 'foo';
INSERT dbo.table(column) SELECT N'foo';
```

As an example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.foo
(
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  bar NVARCHAR(32) COLLATE SQL_Ukrainian_CP1251_CI_AS
);

INSERT dbo.foo SELECT 1,'АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛ';
INSERT dbo.foo SELECT 2,N'АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛ';

SELECT ID, bar FROM dbo.foo;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.foo;
```

Results:

```
ID    bar
----  --------------
1     ????????Z?????
2     АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛ
```

And to show how this affects your insert statement, your string is missing the `N` prefix:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), 'Иванов'),
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), N'Иванов');
```

Results:

```
------    ------
??????    Иванов
```

So, prefix your Unicode strings with `N'a prefix'` or lose data.

Comment: Thanx! looks like it is working, so do i have to use `N` each time before inserting any text in to every field?

Comment: You need it for any insert into a column that is Unicode (nchar/nvarchar) and when the string literal may contain characters outside the basic ASCII character set. So, in essence: yes.

Answer (score 1):

While Aaron Bertrand gave a good explanation why do you getting such a results, I'd say there's a way not to prefix all you strings with russian letters with `'N'`.
As far as I know, you have just set your server collation properly. So if you set your collation, for example, like `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`, server could treat varchar with russian letters properly:

```
select
    'español', '平成年月日', 'иван',
    serverproperty('collation')
```

results:

```
espanol ?????   иван    Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
```

As you see, spanish and Chinese strings are not treated properly while russian strings are. So you can insert data into nvarchar columns without prefixing strings with `'N'`

That said, I'm using nvarchar data type in our database as default strings, nvarchar parameters in stored procedures. I very rarely use russian strings in code (only when I want to test something), and I've never used `N'string'` syntax.

While having correct default collation could be handy, there's problem with this solution - it's not easy to [change default collation on installed SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx), so you have to be careful when installing SQL Server instance and choose collation properly.

Comment: While this can allow you to be lazy in this case, the problem is that [changing the server collation is a pain](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx) (and may cause other problems), and the habit of not prefixing Unicode strings could also lead to problems elsewhere - you're not always going to have the magical ability to change server collation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, changing server collation is a pain indeed, but this information could be useful to OP

Comment: I think your answer should not imply that changing server collation is easier than adding an N prefix to strings that should be prefixed by N regardless of server collation. Or maybe include all of the steps of changing server collation (and the gotchas). Right now it sounds like this is easier, and it's not.